# How do I password protect an HTTP Get Request on my Apache Tomcat server?

Tags: java, apache, http, tomcat, servlets

I want to send a user some data only if they correctly supply the username and password in the header of their HTTP request.

I tried doing this via the HttpServletReqest login() method, but it hasn't worked.

this is my server's doGet method:

```
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    String token = "abcdef";
    request.login("User", "Pass");
    out.print("{\n\"Authentication Token\" : \"" + token + "\"\n}");

    out.flush();

}
```

and here is the Header for the Get Request I'm sending (via Advanced Rest Client for Google Chrome)

```
Authorization: Basic VXNlcjpQYXNz //"User" "Pass" converted to Base 64 by Advanced Rest Client
```

But it keeps throwing the "Login Failed" Servlet exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to configure user and role in tomcat's tomcat-users.xml file..
and also configure URL in web.xml file for using this authentication..
 giving you sample code below...

```
tomcat-users.xml file:

<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<tomcat-users>
  <role rolename="tomcat"/>
  <user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat"/>
  <user username="myname" password="mypassword" roles="tomcat"/>
  <user username="test" password="test"/>
</tomcat-users>

web.xml file :

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="tomcat-demo" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>TestServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>test.TestServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>TestServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/test</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Wildcard means whole app requires authentication</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/test</url-pattern>
            <http-method>GET</http-method>

        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>tomcat</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>

        <user-data-constraint>
            <!-- transport-guarantee can be CONFIDENTIAL, INTEGRAL, or NONE -->
            <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
        </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>

    <login-config>
        <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    </login-config>

</web-app>
```